# Nested routes and has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Lets say I have a structure, such as the below:

```
Doctor has_many :appointments
Patient has_many :appointments
doctors has_many :patients :through :appointments
patients has_many :doctors :through :appointments
```

Can I nest appointments under doctors? Will this cause any limitations or is it against best practices?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'nest'? Do you mean nesting routes?

Comment: Yes, I will make an edit to clarify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested routes will only affect the way you access the resources. There will not be any limitation at the Model level due to how you chose to organize the routes. If it makes sense in the context of your application there is no reason not to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I just spent a long time learning how to actually nest a route yesterday. I didn't want to invest all of that time again to find out I broke something.